# How to call a component from an onClick event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to make it possible that whenever I click on a button (which is a component itself) a modal component  is called. I did some research but none of the solutions is doing what I need. It partially works but not quite the way I want it to because, once the state is set to true and I modify the quantity in the Meals.js and click again the modal doesn't show up

Meals.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Card } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import NumericInput from "react-numeric-input";
import AddBtn from "./AddtoCartBTN";



function Meals({ product }) {
  const [Food, setFood] = useState(0);



  return (
    <Card className="my-3 p-3 rounded">
      <Link to={`/product/${product.id}`}>
        <Card.Img src={product.image} />
      </Link>
      <Card.Body>
        <Link to={`/product/${product.id}`} style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
          <Card.Title as="div">
            <strong>{product.name}</strong>
          </Card.Title>
        </Link>
        Quantity{" "}
        <NumericInput min={0} max={100} onChange={(value) => setFood(value)} />
        
        {/* <NumericInput min={0} max={100} onChange={ChangeHandler(value)} /> */}
        <Card.Text as="h6" style={{ color: "red" }}>
          {Food === 0 ? product.price : Food * product.price} CFA
        </Card.Text>
        <AddBtn quantity={Food} price={product.price} productId={product.id} />
      </Card.Body>
    </Card>
  );
}

export default Meals;
```

AddToCartBtn.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { addToCart } from "../actions/cmdActions";
import toast, { Toaster } from "react-hot-toast";
import CartModal from "./CartModal";

function AddtoCartBTN({ quantity, price, productId }) {
  const AddedPrice = quantity * price;
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false)

  const notify = () => toast("Ajout Effectue !", {});

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const AddtoCart = () => {
    // console.log("Added to cart !");
    // console.log("Added : ", AddedPrice);
    if (AddedPrice > 0) {
      dispatch(addToCart(productId, AddedPrice));
      notify();
      setShowModal(true)
     
    }
  };


  return (
    <button
      className="btn btn-primary d-flex justify-content-center"
      onClick={AddtoCart}
    >
      Ajouter
      {showModal && <CartModal/>}
      <Toaster />
    </button>
  );
}

export default AddtoCartBTN;
```

Modal.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Modal, Button, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function CartModal ()  {
    const [modalShow, setModalShow] = useState(true);

    let history = useHistory();

    const panierHandler = () => {
      history.push('/commander')
    }


    const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
    const { cartItems } = cart;
  

  
    function MyVerticallyCenteredModal(props) {
      return (
        <Modal
          {...props}
          size="md"
          aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
          centered
          backdrop="static"
        
         
        >
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
              <b style={{ color: "red" }}> choix de produits</b> <br />
            
            </Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            <Row>
              <Col><b>Nom</b></Col>
              <Col><b>Quantite</b></Col>
            </Row><hr/>
           {cartItems && cartItems.map((item,i)=>(
             <>
              <Row key={i}>
              <Col>{item.name}</Col>
              <Col>{item.total / item.price}</Col>
            </Row><hr/>
            </>
           ))}
          </Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              alignItems: "center",
              justifyContent: "center",
            }}
          >
          
            
            <Button
              // onClick={props.onHide}
              onClick={panierHandler}
            
            >
              Aller au Panier
            </Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
      );
    }
  
    return (
      <>
        <MyVerticallyCenteredModal
          show={modalShow}
          onHide={() => setModalShow(false)}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
export default CartModal
```

Answer (score 1):

in AddToCartBtn.js, you can pass setShowModal as a prop.

> `{showModal && <CartModal setShowModal={setShowModal} />}`

And the, in Modal.js, you can use the prop setShowModal to set the value to false

> `<MyVerticallyCenteredModal show={true} onHide={() => setShowModal(false)} />`

Eliminate the state in Modal.js, keep visible as always true

Comment: This actually makes the modal visible at all times. can't do anything else. What I need is to only make it appear everytime I click on that button.